# How do I debug a twitter bootstrap modal box?

Tags: jsp, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to implement the standard modal box using Twitter's bootstrap. I have it working on my plain Apache server, but its not working in a JSP using Tomcat6.

I can't figure out how to approach debugging it. I probably have something mis-copies, but I can't see what.

Here is the applicable code:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">XXX</a>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >Launch Modal</a>

<script src="/javascript/jquery-1.7.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascript/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
```

Note: both jquery and bootstrap are loaded in order.

Comment: have you checked the console ? are all the bootstrap resources being loaded properly?

Comment: Also, make sure that **jQuery** is loaded before **bootstrap-modal.js**.  And, if you want the `.fade` class to do anything you're going to need to include **bootstrap-transitions.js**.

Comment: In my case, sometime my breakpoint does not work. I put breakpoint at my js script inside modal bootstrap. I have tried using UC Browser, Firefox, and Firebug debugger. All of it does not work the breakpoint is not working. But I am confused, is my question good enough or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@keshav had the key, use the javascript console, which showed that my URL for loading jquery was wrong. Fixed that and all is fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the record- when I load bootstrap-modal.js AFTER I load jquery, bootstrap's modal function does not work. 
When I load bootstrap-modal.js BEFORE I load jquery, bootstrap's modal function works properly.