# meteor: how to change include order of packages

Tags: meteor

in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946443/how-do-i-debug-a-twitter-bootstrap-modal-box?rq=1) post on stackoverflow, the autor recommends to include the `bootstrap.js` **before** the `jquery.js`. in other circumstances he wrote, that the bootstrap modal won't work properly. So i had a look at the sources of my startpage, and i saw, that meteor includes bootstrap **after** jquery. 
And now my question: **How can i change the order of the included packages in meteor?**

EDIT:
The reason, why i ask, is that i have problems with bootstrap modal. For example modals disappears when i press a button inside or type something into an input...

Comment: I'm using meteor 1.6, If the packages have no dependencies, the order of the packages included in /.meteor/packages file, is the order of load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order the packages are added depends on their filenames.

The default order should be fine, I also use the modal with both the jquery and bootstrap packages without issue. Are you adding these script tags yourself? You don't really need them.

Why not install the packages with meteor:

```
meteor add bootstrap
meteor add jquery
```

Comment: I added these packages with meteor. The simpler modal i have, work fine, but the ones with included for example tabs or alerts, causes issues.

Comment: I use tabs & alerts without problems with the standard meteor setup. Do you have any examples of them running live?

Comment: No, sorry. I have no public live examples yet. But i use an idle timer to monitor page activity (especially _keydown_'s). And since i included this class, i ran into issues with bootstrap modals. On one client the modal doesn't show, on the other the modal disappears "randomly" or on keydown, and so on. So i removed the affected modals and replaced them with other solutions. But it still would be nice to know, where the problems come from... :)

Comment: Are you using `$(..).modal('show')` or the html tags `id='xx' role=dialog` with `<a href='xx'...`?

Comment: At first i call `$(...).modal({show:false})`. Then i set the default values in my input fields. And finally i show the modal with `$(...).modal('show')`.

Comment: Try without the first call, its not necessarily needed. could you double check you dont also have those html tags. Instead of the idletimer on key events have you considered checking if the window is active/in focus (like fb does to check whether you're online)?

Comment: I used the `role="dialog"`, the `aria-labelledby="..."` and the `aria-hidden="true"` attributes for the modal and the click event of an `<a>` *without* `href` or `data-target` attributes for calling the modal. --- To check, if the window is in focus, is a good idea! I use the timer on key events to check if a user is typing something into an input field and then i display this state to the other users (like fb or skype it does). Maybe i can check, if the input field has the focus? I will try it.

Comment: Don't use the role=dialog/role=button stuff because its a bit glitchy when it comes to using the javascript as well. The modal closes after a while and has all these weird behaviours,

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the answers! I will try this on occasion. :)